# Windows Setting inhibiting More than 2 tabs to open from script file

Tags: command-line, batch-file, internet-explorer, javascript, vbscript

I have a number of sites that I have to monitor as part of my job. I created a .vbs (though in troubleshooting this issue, I also created and had the same problem with .js and .bat files). This file simply opens a new Internet Explorer window and then would put a new tab for each website I would need. This is the code:

```
Const navOpenInBackgroundTab = &H1000

site1 = "http://www.google.com"
site2 = "http://www.yahoo.com"
site3 = "http://www.bing.com"
site4 = "http://www.duckduckgo.com"

Set oIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

oIE.Visible = True
oIE.Navigate2 site1
oIE.Navigate2 site2,navOpenInBackgroundTab
oIE.Navigate2 site3,navOpenInBackgroundTab
oIE.Navigate2 site4,navOpenInBackgroundTab

Set oIE = Nothing
```

Executing this file has been flawless for me and I have been able to set it to automatically run through the scheduler to automate my task monitoring until recently. Now when I run it, it only opens the first 2 tabs regardless of how many links I have as part of the script.

I have been scouring the internet in search of a solution on this and haven't found anything. There are some other computers on which I can get this to work properly, though not mine anymore. Is this just some Windows setting that is inhibiting the script from properly opening all of the tabs? Where should I look to change/fix it?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: You could maybe add a small sleep time between each site.

Comment: So I attempted this and it didn't work either. But it also wouldn't explain the change from why it is working on some computers but not on others.

Comment: Find the difference between computers where it's working or not and report on it : operating system versions and applied updates. You could also try to start IE in Safe mode.

Answer (score 1):

Give a try for this vbscript :

```
Option Explicit
Dim oIE,site1,URL,ArrayURLS
Set oIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
site1 = "http://www.duckduckgo.com"
oIE.Visible = True
oIE.Navigate2 site1

ArrayURLS = Array("http://www.google.com","http://www.yahoo.com","https://superuser.com",_
"https://stackoverflow.com","https://security.stackexchange.com/","https://pastebin.com")

For Each URL In ArrayURLS
    Call OpenTab(URL)
Next

Set oIE = Nothing
wscript.quit
'**********************************************
Sub OpenTab(URL)
Const navOpenInBackgroundTab = &H1000
    oIE.Visible = True
    oIE.Navigate2 URL,navOpenInBackgroundTab
    Do
        WScript.Sleep 100
    Loop While oIE.Busy
End sub
'********************************************
```